# Compiler error with using std::list

Tags: c++, templates

I have this simple function to check if a value is in list:

```
template <class T>
bool IsinList(list<T> l, T x)
{
    for(list<T>::iterator it=list.begin(); it != list.end(); it++)
    {
        if (*it == x)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I used the function in the same .cpp file like this:

```
if (!IsinList (words, temp))   
    goodwords.push_back(temp);
```

but I am getting this error :

```
'std::list' : use of class template requires template argument list
```

and I cant figure out what the problem is. I checked in previous asked questions and it didn't help.
Can you explain to me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Needs more [typename](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords).

Comment: A side note, you should use [std::find](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/find.html) instead of implementing similar functionality of your own.

Comment: A variable called `list` would not be the best idea, in any case

Comment: I know..I just didn't notice..I hope the editors of the website will not block me from posting more stupid questions..lol

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typo there:

```
list.begin() / list.end()
```

should be

```
l.begin() / l.end()
```

Your variable is called `l`, not `list`.

EDIT:

As Martinho pointed out, this might not be enough. Some compilers will accept this, but since the iterator depends on the template argument, you might need a typename:

```
typename list<T>::iterator it=list.begin()
```

Comment: @sbi yes, dependent names and all.

Comment: As noted in the edited post, not necessarily. Some compilers accept dependent names as-is.

Comment: Where by "some compilers" we mostly mean "MSVC". The reason is that MSVC doesn't implement two-phase lookup properly, it only does the second phase. To over-simplify a bit, it's in the first phase that the `typename` is needed. So even if your compiler accepts the code without it, you should put it there anyway in case you ever use a different compiler.

Comment: @SteveJessop yup, I was talking about MSVC. I hope the op sees the comments, I can't seem to target him with @.

Comment: Hmm, RTL text doesn't mesh well with the syntax for addressing comments, I think. I wonder whether this will help: @זאבי כהן

Answer (score 2):

You made a typo (`list` vs. `l`) and did not specify that `list<T>::iterator` is a `typename`. Further, you should pass the `list` and the search argument by reference-to-const. All in all, it should look like this:

```
template <class T>
bool IsinList(const list<T>& l, const T& x)
{
    typename list<T>::const_iterator first = l.begin(), last = l.end();
    for(; first != last; ++first)
    {
        if (*it == x)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

That said, still don't use this. Much better to use [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) instead

```
if (std::find(words.begin(), words.end(), temp)==words.end())
{
  goodwords.push_back(temp);
}
```

Comment: @זאבי כהן if you have c++11, you can also use [std::copy_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy)

Comment: @juanchopanza: and if you don't have C++11, you can use `std::remove_copy_if` with the opposite predicate. Just write `IsNotInList` as well as `IsInList`.